# Is there a way to include limit in hibernate search like exludeLimit()?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am using a range query in hibernate search which I expect to be as this - `a <= b <= c`.

However, I can't find any documentation in *hibernate* search which can help me to achieve this. Is it possible using directly *hibernate* search or do I need to have a workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just do not call `excludeLimit()`. Limits are included by default, so what you want is actually the default behavior.